# Require local node modules with absolute paths doesn't work on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm developing a Node application with several modules.
My node-application is transpiled with Babel to `/dist/app`.

This is an example-structure

```
.
|- main
|   |- config.js
|   |- factories
|   |     |- example.js
```

This is **config.js**:

```
const ex = require("/main/factories/example");
```

I launch config.js with `node dist/app/main/config.js`.
The resulting error is:

> Error: Cannot find module '/main/factories/example";

However when using `const ex = require("./factories/example");` it works as it should.

This problem only occurs on **Windows** (testing Windows 8.1), both OS X and Linux are fine.

**What is the problem here?**

Comment: Could you flesh out the code sample a bit? What we can see so far doesn't actually call `require`.

Comment: I only forgot the `require`

Comment: It's the other way around, the code works as expected on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the other way around, the code works as expected on Windows. `/main/factories/example` means `C:/main/factories/example` on Windows. It works on OSX/Linux because of some reason (NODE_PATH being set probably). I'd suggest to not rely on a side effect to have a working code and don't use relative path either (entirely dependant on the working directory), you should build your absolute path like this:

```
const ex = require(__dirname + "/factories/example");
```

Answer (score 3):

I think maybe the `NODE_PATH` cause this your issue. Refer to this article [`Better local require() paths for Node.js`](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520). There are several ways to require local node modules

- [The Symlink](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520#1-the-symlink).

  Create a symlink under node_modules to your app directory:

  - Linux: `ln -nsf node_modules app`
  - Windows: `mklink /D app node_modules`
- [The Module](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520#3-the-module)

  Install some module:

  `npm install app-module-path --save`

  In your app.js, before any require() calls:

  `require('app-module-path').addPath(__dirname + '/app');`

  In your very/far/away/module.js:

  `var Article = require('models/article');`
- [The startup script](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520#5-the-start-up-script)

  Linux, create app.sh in your project root:

  ```
   #!/bin/sh
   NODE_PATH=. node app.js
  ```

  Windows, create app.bat in your project root:

  ```
   @echo off
   cmd.exe /C "set NODE_PATH=.&& node app.js"
  ```

Hope it could help you.